# RPi OpenVPN server: manage users

Tags: raspbian, openvpn

I have successfully configured OpenVPN as per this [1and1 instruction](http://www.1and1.ca/digitalguide/server/configuration/vpn-server-set-up-via-raspberry-pi-and-openvpn/). Now I am trying to figure out how to add/remove users and change their passwords.

I have been able to do this by, pretty much, going from the beginning and recreating all certificates, which is a bit of a hustle, to say the least.

Is there a short-handed way of doing this?

When I'm trying to skip to

```
./build-key-pass newuser
```

I get

```
Please edit the vars script to reflect your configuration,
then source it with "source ./vars".
Next, to start with a fresh PKI configuration and to delete any
previous certificates and keys, run "./clean-all".
Finally, you can run this tool (pkitool) to build certificates/keys.
```

Which throws me back a long way.

Comment: Have you looked at [this?](https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/1073-bash-script-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-key-and-request-csr)